# How can I add scrollbar to my labels using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, scrollbar

As a part of my prep for the GRE exam I developed this small quiz app. The idea is very simple, it generates random sentences using GRE words and then substitutes the roots of GRE words to a blank. The app is not ideal, but it does the job. One big issue I am trying to tackle in the code is the addition of a scrollbar on the side. I do not want to reengineer the structure of the code too much... and make it work with a quick and easy adjustment... but cannot think of anything simple...

Let me know what would be the most frictionless way to create a functional scrollbar on the side.

There were a few answers I was able to find online, but most of them discussed the usage of text instead of labels...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk.stem.snowball import EnglishStemmer
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import time
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()
window.wm_title('GRE prep')
dictionary=PyDictionary()


df = pd.read_csv("/Users/vladimirbarshchuk/Downloads/DictionaryV21.csv")
for x in range(len(df["Word"])):
    df["Links"]= "https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/{}.html"
for x in range(len(df["Word"])):
    df["Links"][x] = "https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/{}.html".format(df["Word"][x])
    
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
df["Word"][141]="hegemonic"
stemmer = EnglishStemmer()
def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text



from tkinter import * 

e = Entry(window, width =50)
e.pack()
count = 0 
given_word = []
answers = []
def work():
    random_link = random.choice(df["Links"])
    word_index = df[df['Links'] == random_link].index[0]
    htmldata = getdata(random_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.find_all(id="gexv2row1")
    word= df["Word"].loc[word_index]
    answers.append(word)
    stem = stemmer.stem(word)
    clean_text = text[0].get_text().replace("\n"or"'\n"or"\n'", "")

    if stem not in clean_text:
        stem = stem[:-1]
        #print(clean_text.replace(stem_1, "_____"))
        message = Label(window, text = "EX : " + clean_text.replace(stem, "_____"), fg="black")
        context = Label(window, text ="Definition : " + df["My explanation"].loc[word_index], fg = "grey")
        message.pack()
        context.pack()

    else: 
        #print(clean_text.replace(stem, "_____"))
        message = Label(window,  text = "EX : " + clean_text.replace(stem, "_____"),fg="black")
        context = Label(window, text ="Definition : " + df["My explanation"].loc[word_index], fg = "grey")
        message.pack()
        context.pack()
        name = e.get()
        
    return 
        

sentenceButton = Button(window, text = "Show Sentence", command = work)
sentenceButton.pack()

for x in range(len(answers)):
    count=count+1   
    print(count)

def check():
    print("Correct answer:", answers[count-1])
    correct_answer = Label(window, text = answers[count-1], fg = "green")
    incorrect_answer = Label(window, text = answers[count-1], fg = "red")
    a = e.get()
    
    if a == correct_answer.cget("text"):
            correct_answer.pack()
    else:
            incorrect_answer.pack()
            
new = Button(window, text = "Check!", command = check)
new.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You cannot add a scrollbar to a Label

Comment: You can use a [ScrolledText widget](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) instead of a Label.